# VBA Access 2010 for Changing the system date, time

Tags: vba, system-configuration

Need a VBA Code for Access 2010 to Change/Set the system date, time.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Refer this link http://www.cpearson.com/excel/FileTimes.htm

Answer (score -1):

Heres a sample code from FREEVBCODE.com
Make a Module, and paste the following code:

```
Declare Function GetLocaleInfo Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetLocaleInfoA" (ByVal Locale As Long, ByVal LCType As Long, ByVal lpLCData As String, ByVal cchData As Long) As Long

Declare Function SetLocaleInfo Lib "kernel32" Alias "SetLocaleInfoA" (ByVal Locale As Long, ByVal LCType As Long, ByVal lpLCData As String) As Boolean

Declare Function GetUserDefaultLCID% Lib "kernel32" ()

Public Const LOCALE_ICENTURY = &H24
Public Const LOCALE_ICOUNTRY = &H5
Public Const LOCALE_ICURRDIGITS = &H19
Public Const LOCALE_ICURRENCY = &H1B
Public Const LOCALE_IDATE = &H21
Public Const LOCALE_IDAYLZERO = &H26
Public Const LOCALE_IDEFAULTCODEPAGE = &HB
Public Const LOCALE_IDEFAULTCOUNTRY = &HA
Public Const LOCALE_IDEFAULTLANGUAGE = &H9
Public Const LOCALE_IDIGITS = &H11
Public Const LOCALE_IINTLCURRDIGITS = &H1A
Public Const LOCALE_ILANGUAGE = &H1
Public Const LOCALE_ILDATE = &H22
Public Const LOCALE_ILZERO = &H12
Public Const LOCALE_IMEASURE = &HD
Public Const LOCALE_IMONLZERO = &H27
Public Const LOCALE_INEGCURR = &H1C
Public Const LOCALE_INEGSEPBYSPACE = &H57
Public Const LOCALE_INEGSIGNPOSN = &H53
Public Const LOCALE_INEGSYMPRECEDES = &H56
Public Const LOCALE_IPOSSEPBYSPACE = &H55
Public Const LOCALE_IPOSSIGNPOSN = &H52
Public Const LOCALE_IPOSSYMPRECEDES = &H54
Public Const LOCALE_ITIME = &H23
Public Const LOCALE_ITLZERO = &H25
Public Const LOCALE_NOUSEROVERRIDE = &H80000000
Public Const LOCALE_S1159 = &H28
Public Const LOCALE_S2359 = &H29
Public Const LOCALE_SABBREVCTRYNAME = &H7
Public Const LOCALE_SABBREVDAYNAME1 = &H31
Public Const LOCALE_SABBREVDAYNAME2 = &H32
Public Const LOCALE_SABBREVDAYNAME3 = &H33
Public Const LOCALE_SABBREVDAYNAME4 = &H34
Public Const LOCALE_SABBREVDAYNAME5 = &H35
Public Const LOCALE_SABBREVDAYNAME6 = &H36
Public Const LOCALE_SABBREVDAYNAME7 = &H37
Public Const LOCALE_SABBREVLANGNAME = &H3
Public Const LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME1 = &H44
Public Const LOCALE_SCOUNTRY = &H6
Public Const LOCALE_SCURRENCY = &H14
Public Const LOCALE_SDATE = &H1D
Public Const LOCALE_SDAYNAME1 = &H2A
Public Const LOCALE_SDAYNAME2 = &H2B
Public Const LOCALE_SDAYNAME3 = &H2C
Public Const LOCALE_SDAYNAME4 = &H2D
Public Const LOCALE_SDAYNAME5 = &H2E
Public Const LOCALE_SDAYNAME6 = &H2F
Public Const LOCALE_SDAYNAME7 = &H30
Public Const LOCALE_SDECIMAL = &HE
Public Const LOCALE_SENGCOUNTRY = &H1002
Public Const LOCALE_SENGLANGUAGE = &H1001
Public Const LOCALE_SGROUPING = &H10
Public Const LOCALE_SINTLSYMBOL = &H15
Public Const LOCALE_SLANGUAGE = &H2
Public Const LOCALE_SLIST = &HC
Public Const LOCALE_SLONGDATE = &H20
Public Const LOCALE_SMONDECIMALSEP = &H16
Public Const LOCALE_SMONGROUPING = &H18
Public Const LOCALE_SMONTHNAME1 = &H38
Public Const LOCALE_SMONTHNAME10 = &H41
Public Const LOCALE_SMONTHNAME11 = &H42
Public Const LOCALE_SMONTHNAME12 = &H43
Public Const LOCALE_SMONTHNAME2 = &H39
Public Const LOCALE_SMONTHNAME3 = &H3A
Public Const LOCALE_SMONTHNAME4 = &H3B
Public Const LOCALE_SMONTHNAME5 = &H3C
Public Const LOCALE_SMONTHNAME6 = &H3D
Public Const LOCALE_SMONTHNAME7 = &H3E
Public Const LOCALE_SMONTHNAME8 = &H3F
Public Const LOCALE_SMONTHNAME9 = &H40
Public Const LOCALE_SMONTHOUSANDSEP = &H17
Public Const LOCALE_SNATIVECTRYNAME = &H8
Public Const LOCALE_SNATIVEDIGITS = &H13
Public Const LOCALE_SNATIVELANGNAME = &H4
Public Const LOCALE_SNEGATIVESIGN = &H51
Public Const LOCALE_SPOSITIVESIGN = &H50
Public Const LOCALE_SSHORTDATE = &H1F
Public Const LOCALE_STHOUSAND = &HF
Public Const LOCALE_STIME = &H1E
Public Const LOCALE_STIMEFORMAT = &H1003

Public Const LOCALE_ICOUNTRY = &H5
Public Const LOCALE_ICURRDIGITS = &H19
Public Const LOCALE_ICURRENCY = &H1B
Public Const LOCALE_IDATE = &H21
Public Const LOCALE_IDAYLZERO = &H26
Public Const LOCALE_IDEFAULTCODEPAGE = &HB
Public Const LOCALE_IDEFAULTCOUNTRY = &HA
Public Const LOCALE_IDEFAULTLANGUAGE = &H9
Public Const LOCALE_IDIGITS = &H11
Public Const LOCALE_IINTLCURRDIGITS = &H1A
Public Const LOCALE_ILANGUAGE = &H1
Public Const LOCALE_ILDATE = &H22
Public Const LOCALE_ILZERO = &H12
Public Const LOCALE_IMEASURE = &HD
Public Const LOCALE_IMONLZERO = &H27
Public Const LOCALE_INEGCURR = &H1C
Public Const LOCALE_INEGSEPBYSPACE = &H57
Public Const LOCALE_INEGSIGNPOSN = &H53
Public Const LOCALE_INEGSYMPRECEDES = &H56
Public Const LOCALE_IPOSSEPBYSPACE = &H55
Public Const LOCALE_IPOSSIGNPOSN = &H52
Public Const LOCALE_IPOSSYMPRECEDES = &H54
Public Const LOCALE_ITIME = &H23
Public Const LOCALE_ITLZERO = &H25
Public Const LOCALE_NOUSEROVERRIDE = &H80000000
Public Const LOCALE_S1159 = &H28
Public Const LOCALE_S2359 = &H29
Public Const LOCALE_SABBREVCTRYNAME = &H7
Public Const LOCALE_SABBREVDAYNAME1 = &H31
Public Const LOCALE_SABBREVDAYNAME2 = &H32
Public Const LOCALE_SABBREVDAYNAME3 = &H33
Public Const LOCALE_SABBREVDAYNAME4 = &H34
Public Const LOCALE_SABBREVDAYNAME5 = &H35
Public Const LOCALE_SABBREVDAYNAME6 = &H36
Public Const LOCALE_SABBREVDAYNAME7 = &H37
Public Const LOCALE_SABBREVLANGNAME = &H3
Public Const LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME1 = &H44
Public Const LOCALE_SCOUNTRY = &H6
Public Const LOCALE_SCURRENCY = &H14
Public Const LOCALE_SDATE = &H1D
Public Const LOCALE_SDAYNAME1 = &H2A
Public Const LOCALE_SDAYNAME2 = &H2B
Public Const LOCALE_SDAYNAME3 = &H2C
Public Const LOCALE_SDAYNAME4 = &H2D
Public Const LOCALE_SDAYNAME5 = &H2E
Public Const LOCALE_SDAYNAME6 = &H2F
Public Const LOCALE_SDAYNAME7 = &H30
Public Const LOCALE_SDECIMAL = &HE
Public Const LOCALE_SENGCOUNTRY = &H1002
Public Const LOCALE_SENGLANGUAGE = &H1001
Public Const LOCALE_SGROUPING = &H10
Public Const LOCALE_SINTLSYMBOL = &H15
Public Const LOCALE_SLANGUAGE = &H2
Public Const LOCALE_SLIST = &HC
Public Const LOCALE_SLONGDATE = &H20
Public Const LOCALE_SMONDECIMALSEP = &H16
Public Const LOCALE_SMONGROUPING = &H18
Public Const LOCALE_SMONTHNAME1 = &H38
Public Const LOCALE_SMONTHNAME10 = &H41
Public Const LOCALE_SMONTHNAME11 = &H42
Public Const LOCALE_SMONTHNAME12 = &H43
Public Const LOCALE_SMONTHNAME2 = &H39
Public Const LOCALE_SMONTHNAME3 = &H3A
Public Const LOCALE_SMONTHNAME4 = &H3B
Public Const LOCALE_SMONTHNAME5 = &H3C
Public Const LOCALE_SMONTHNAME6 = &H3D
Public Const LOCALE_SMONTHNAME7 = &H3E
Public Const LOCALE_SMONTHNAME8 = &H3F
Public Const LOCALE_SMONTHNAME9 = &H40
Public Const LOCALE_SMONTHOUSANDSEP = &H17
Public Const LOCALE_SNATIVECTRYNAME = &H8
Public Const LOCALE_SNATIVEDIGITS = &H13
Public Const LOCALE_SNATIVELANGNAME = &H4
Public Const LOCALE_SNEGATIVESIGN = &H51
Public Const LOCALE_SPOSITIVESIGN = &H50
Public Const LOCALE_SSHORTDATE = &H1F
Public Const LOCALE_STHOUSAND = &HF
Public Const LOCALE_STIME = &H1E
Public Const LOCALE_STIMEFORMAT = &H1003



Public Sub Get_locale() ' Retrieve the regional setting

  Dim Symbol As String
  Dim iRet1 As Long
  Dim iRet2 As Long
  Dim lpLCDataVar As String
  Dim Pos As Integer
  Dim Locale As Long

  Locale = GetUserDefaultLCID()

'LOCALE_SDATE is the constant for the date separator
'as stated in declarations
'for any other locale setting just change the constant

'Function can also be re-written to take the
'locale symbol being requested as a parameter

  iRet1 = GetLocaleInfo(Locale, LOCALE_SDATE, _
  lpLCDataVar, 0)
  Symbol = String$(iRet1, 0)

  iRet2 = GetLocaleInfo(Locale, LOCALE_SDATE, Symbol, iRet1)
  Pos = InStr(Symbol, Chr$(0))
  If Pos > 0 Then
       Symbol = Left$(Symbol, Pos - 1)
       MsgBox "Regional Setting = " + Symbol
  End If

End Sub

Public Sub Set_locale() 'Change the regional setting

  Dim Symbol As String
  Dim iRet As Long
  Dim Locale As Long

'LOCALE_SDATE is the constant for the date separator
'as stated in declarations
'for any other locale setting just change the constant

'Function can also be re-written to take the
'locale information being set as a parameter

  Locale = GetUserDefaultLCID() 'Get user Locale ID
  Symbol = "-" 'New character for the locale
  iRet = SetLocaleInfo(Locale, LOCALE_SDATE, Symbol)

End Sub
```